# How to build nested routes in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I defined my routes in the separate file:

**PostRoutes.kt:**

```
fun Route.getPostsRoute() {
    get("/posts") {
        call.respondText("Posts")
    }
}

// Some other routes

fun Application.postRoutes() {
    routing {
        getPostsRoute()
        // Some other routes
    }
}
```

And I setup these routes in **Application.kt** as it shown below:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    routing { // I want to provide the root endpoint (/api/v1) here
        postRoutes()
    }
}
```

How can I setup my root endpoint (`/api/v1`) in this case?

**P.S.** I've checked their docs, it says to use nested `route`s but I can't because I need to call `routing` in `postRoutes()` that breaks nested routes.

**P.P.S.** I am a noobie in Ktor and Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

You can either wrap the `getPostsRoute()` with the `route("/api/v1")` inside the `postRoutes` method or get rid of the `postRoutes` method and nest your routes inside the `routing {}`.

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 5555, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        postRoutes()
    }.start(wait = false)
}

fun Route.getPostsRoute() {
    get("/posts") {
        call.respondText("Posts")
    }
}

fun Application.postRoutes() {
    routing {
        route("/api/v1") {
            getPostsRoute()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yeah, they offer this variant in their docs but it’s not convenient when u have a lot of endpoints. How to make it for my case? When I have many routes in many files and every file has an entry point to setup its routes. I don’t want to setup a root path for every file and I don’t want to register every endpoint in a single place, it will be messy.

Comment: You don't have to set up a root path for every file. Just define any number of routes in the **entry method**, like `getPostsRoute`, and call it inside the centralized `routing` block.

Comment: how can I make not to set up getPosts, getTags, putPost and +100500 endpoints in a single place? Can I setup just my `postRoutes`’ `tagRoutes` and so on in a single place with the root path, and every so entrypoint will setup its routes? It’s much more convenient for my case, unfortunately

Comment: Yes, you can. What's the problem with defining them in that way?